# ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable?

Tags: python

i added the python path in environment variable then also it is giving me same error so please anyone can help me

> (py1) C:\Users\NIKITA GULHANE\projects\raksh>python manage.py
>   runserver Traceback (most recent call last):   File "manage.py", line
>   8, in 
>       from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line   File
>   "C:\Users\NIKITA~1\Envs\py1\lib\site-packages\django__init__.py",
>   line 1, in 
>       from django.utils.version import get_version   File "C:\Users\NIKITA~1\Envs\py1\lib\site-packages\django\utils\version.py",
>   line 1, in 
>       import datetime ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'datetime'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 14, in 
    ) from exc
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?

Comment: Please show how you are setting the python path - something has gone wrong if it can no longer import `datetime`. If you have activated the `py1` virtual env and installed Django in it, then you shouldn’t need to set the python path.

Comment: Thank you for giving me replay, I am using windows 10 and python path

Comment: C:\Users\NIKITA GULHANE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37 .This url set in computer property in advanced system settings option  environment variables available click on that button then popup the window .         in user variable create new variable name PYTHONPATH and system variable added the python installed path in c drive

Comment: That python path looks incorrect to me. Was it set to a different value before or did you change it? I might try removing it. I don’t use Python on Windows so I don’t have any more advice. [This page](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#finding-modules) might help.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I found you have to ensure Django is imported in the file wsgi.py.

Hope [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65479892/couldnt-import-django-are-you-sure-its-installed-and-available-on-your-python) is useful

Comment: Still showing `ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?`