# Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? --> WSGI.PY file

Tags: python, django, wsgi

When I try to execute *py manage.py runserver* I had the following message:

> raise ImportError(
>
> Import Error: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
>
> )

Answer (score 3):

I found a lot of possible solutions on the internet. I suggest first try the following:

Go to the **wsgi.py** file, inside MySite and go to this line:

```
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
```

**Verify that Django is imported**. I use Pycharm, the IDE allowed me to import directly from there.

After this I was able to run manage.py

Comment: It is still showing same ` File "/Users/mac_hd/Desktop/Python/Django_admin_1st/manage.py", line 11, in main
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'`

Answer (score 0):

Try to make it in a virtual environment, it will work:

- First, in cmd type `pip install virtualenvwrapper`
- Make a folder in c drive which will consist all of your django projects like C:/Django
- Then go to cmd and type `mkvirtualenv [name you want to give]` and then close the cmd
- Open it again and then navigate to the folder C:/Django then when on that folder type `workon [the name which you gave]`
- Finally, install django by the pip command and then `runserver`

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the code `@api_view(['GET'])` when i imported a package whose code is `from rest_framework.decorators import api_view`